# How to pass data between unrelated functional components in Reactjs without redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React I have scenario to pass data between two unrelated components. which are completely individual one to another. I have some form data what ever the user types or given data should be display from ComponentA to ComponentB.

what i have done explained below.

I have created a form input box and a button. I created a variable with usestate. I have written a function to submit data. I tried with contexapi but it did not work for me.output should be same user given value updated from componentA to componentB.

Thanks in advance

```
// code
// import { createContext } from "react";
import CompA from "./CompA";
import CompB from "./CompB";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('first')

  // const mydata = createContext();
  // const name = 'Ramu'
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CompA setName={setName} value={name}/>
      <CompB setName={setName} value={name}/>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;

// componentA
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const CompA = ()=>{
  const [name, setName] = useState('first')
  const AHandler = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <h5>Component A</h5>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <form onSubmit={AHandler}>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={AHandler}>Component A</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CompA;

// componentB
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import CompA from './CompA'

const CompB = ({setName, name})=>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    setName(name)
  })
  return(
    <div>
      <h5>The user given input should dispaly in Component B {name}</h5>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CompB;
```

Comment: React Context is one way to do this.  It looks like you are aware of that.  Did you try it?  What issues did you encounter?  Please add that information to your question.

Comment: yes i tried but providers did not work for in that scenario. i know how to pass a single variable. but on click event did not work. that's why I tried in another way. Its fine with contexapi also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to **pass data between two unrelated components** in React, the best approach is often to **lift the state up to a common ancestor** component and then **pass the necessary data down to the components** that need it.

In your case, you have already started to do this by defining the state in the App component and passing it down to CompA and CompB.

**I found some minor issues in your implementation:**

In `CompA`, you are defining a new state name and a new `setName` function. This is unnecessary because you are already passing these as props from the App component. You should use the `name` and `setName` passed as props instead of creating new ones.

In `CompB`, the `useEffect` hook is being used incorrectly. Youre trying to set the name when the component mounts but its already being passed as a prop and will update automatically when the state in App changes.

**This should fix your App Component:**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import CompA from "./CompA";
import CompB from "./CompB";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(''); // Initialize with entpy string

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CompA setName={setName} name={name} />
      <CompB name={name} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Component A:**

```
import React from 'react';

const CompA = ({ setName, name }) => {
  const AHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // No need to do anything here unless you have other logic to implement
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>Component A</h5>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <form onSubmit={AHandler}>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Component A</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompA;
```

**Lastly comp B:**

```
import React from 'react';

const CompB = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h5>The user given input should display in Component B: {name}</h5>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompB;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes its directly updating on key up, But the expected result, should update after on click of submit button.

Comment: Ahh okay, try this instead:

`
const CompA = ({ setName }) => {
  const [localName, setLocalName] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(localName);  // Update shared state on submit
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input onChange={(e) => setLocalName(e.target.value)} value={localName} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
`

Formatting is really bad in comments...

Comment: I tried with same but i did not take new const in conponentA. sorry for format.

Comment: Its working Thanks a lot.

Comment: This approach can make sense if the two components have a _close_ common ancestor, but otherwise can lead to a lot of [prop drilling](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/avoid-prop-drilling-with-react-context-api/).  Worth thinking about for the actual use case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. i understood.